# ASP.NET MVC delete function doesnt return to list

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

My controller doesn't come back to list after deleting an item from the list, in browser it throws this error

> This localhost page can’t be found.
>   No web page was found for the web address: https://localhost:44384/RaidRequests/IndexAsync

This started then I added my pagination, i took care of all other problems with my views, but delete just doesn't work.

this is my delete function in my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int? id)
    {
        var raidRequest = await _context.RaidRequest.FindAsync(id);
        _context.RaidRequest.Remove(raidRequest);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(IndexAsync));
    }
```

and my index looks like this:

```
public async Task<ViewResult> IndexAsync(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSurnameSortParm = sortOrder == "NameSurname" ? "NameSurname_desc" : "NameSurname";
        ViewBag.ReasonSortParm = sortOrder == "Reason" ? "Reason_desc" : "Reason";
        ViewBag.AccessSortParm = sortOrder == "Access" ? "Access_desc" : "Access";
        ViewBag.UserOrAdminSortParm = sortOrder == "UserOrAdmin" ? "UserOrAdmin_desc" : "UserOrAdmin";
        ViewBag.DepartmentSortParm = sortOrder == "Department" ? "Department_desc" : "Department";
        ViewBag.UNCPathSortParm = sortOrder == "UNCPath" ? "UNCPath_desc" : "UNCPath";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var request = from c in _context.RaidRequest
                      select c;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            request = request.Where(s => s.NameSurname.Contains(searchString));
        }
        request = sortOrder switch
        {
            "NameSurname_desc" => request.OrderByDescending(c => c.NameSurname),
            "Reason" => request.OrderBy(c => c.Reason),
            "Reason_desc" => request.OrderByDescending(c => c.Reason),
            "Access" => request.OrderBy(c => c.Access),
            "Access_desc" => request.OrderByDescending(c => c.Access),
            "UserOrAdmin" => request.OrderBy(c => c.UserOrAdmin),
            "UserOrAdmin_desc" => request.OrderByDescending(c => c.UserOrAdmin),
            "Department" => request.OrderBy(c => c.Department),
            "Department_desc" => request.OrderByDescending(c => c.Department),
            "UNCPath" => request.OrderBy(c => c.UNCPath),
            "UNCPath_desc" => request.OrderByDescending(c => c.UNCPath),
            _ => request.OrderBy(c => c.Id),
        };
        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(await PaginatedList<RaidRequest>.CreateAsync(request, page ?? 1, pageSize)); 
    }
```

I think the problem is with the return part.
What do I need to write there for it to go back to the list successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action name is `Index`. The error complains that the URL is :

```
https://localhost:44384/RaidRequests/IndexAsync
```

instead of

```
https://localhost:44384/RaidRequests/Index
```

That's because `nameof(IndexAsync)` returns `IndexAsync` instead of `Index`. The return statement should be :

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: Can you please explain how did you find that the action name is `Index`? I am asking this because I didn't see any attribute over the `IndexAsync` method, neither any method calling `Index` in the OP's question. I just found that OP mentioned *my index looks like this* but it could be an abbreviation for `IndexAsync` as well. I am just curious, am I missing something?

Comment: This worked, i think when i tried this i just forgot to add "" to index. thanks, now i feel a bit stupid :D